# $PropertyType to get array entry

Tags: flowtype

I have a type def like this:

```
type Blah = {
   fields: {
       value: string
   }[]
}
```

we see here fields is a bunch of array entries. I want to get that out via `$PropertyType`.

Doing `$PropertyType<Blah, 'fields'>` gives us the array, is it possible to get the element?

The reason I can't do `type Field = {value:string}` then type Blah = { fields:Field[] }`is because I don't have control over type`Blah`, I am importing it from a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the new [`$ElementType` utility](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) to do this.

[Try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQgNgQwBZQLxQN4Cgq4GYCWEcAJgM4BcmOutUAbgnAK4RVnABOBAdgOY0oAXwDaAXSxCsWUJCgAxIqTJooAEgAKnAPaROoACrgIAHnjIANFADkhYuWsA+GcYVKSqtQFE4EALYQPMBGkCaK9mRWPMx+AEYQnM64NFgAxto8HFB2pFThpKrYuIwsbDaxiEjWkkA)

```
type Blah = {
   fields: {
       value: string
   }[]
}

type Fields = $PropertyType<Blah, 'fields'>
type Field = $ElementType<Fields, number>


const field: Field = {
  value: 'blah'
}
```